# Delete sqlite data in listview on uwp

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, uwp

I have a listview whose data is extracted from sqlite database, as shown below:

I want to check the user click the delete button, then the data on the list is deleted and the data in the sqlite database also deleted.
[image: listview image]
XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListTryout" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"  DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemListView}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="ListTryout_SelectionChanged" Background="{x:Null}" SelectionMode="Single">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,0,0" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Judul}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,0,0" FontSize="17" Text="{Binding JumlahSoal}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="SemiLight"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,10,0,0" FontSize="17" Text="{Binding Durasi}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="SemiLight" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <Line X1="0" X2="1" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10,10,10,0" Stroke="#FF4B4B4B"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <AppBarButton x:Name="deleteItemBtn" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,50,0" Icon="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="deleteItemBtn_Click"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Code:

```
private void ReadTryoutList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReadAllDBName dbName = new ReadAllDBName();
            DB_TryoutList = dbName.GetAllDBName();
            ListTryout.ItemsSource = DB_TryoutList.OrderByDescending(i => i.ID).ToList();//Binding DB data to LISTBOX and Latest contact ID can Display first.  
            if(DB_TryoutList.Count == 0)
            {
                statuskosongStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ListTryout.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                statuskosongStack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                ListTryout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
private void deleteItemBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Db_Helper.DeleteQuiz(currentquiz.ID);
        }
```

DatabaseHelper class:

```
public void CreateDatabase(string DB_PATH)
        {
            if (!CheckFileExists(DB_PATH).Result)
            {
                using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DB_PATH))
                {
                    conn.CreateTable<DBName>();
                }
            }
        }
        private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Insert the new history in the DBName table. 
        public void Insert(DBName dBName)
        {
            using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
            {
                conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    conn.Insert(dBName);
                });

            }
        }

        public DBName ReadName(int quizid)
        {
            using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
            {
                var existingName = conn.Query<DBName>("select * from DBName where ID =" + quizid).FirstOrDefault();
                return existingName;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DBName> ReadAllDBName()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
                {
                    List<DBName> myCollection = conn.Table<DBName>().ToList<DBName>();
                    ObservableCollection<DBName> DBNameList = new ObservableCollection<DBName>(myCollection);
                    return DBNameList;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void DeleteQuiz(string ID)
        {
            using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
            {

                var existingquiz = conn.Query<DBName>("delete from DBName where ID ='" + ID + "'").FirstOrDefault();
                if (existingquiz != null)
                {
                    conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                    {
                        conn.Delete(existingquiz);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried it, but the data can not be deleted on listview and also on the sqlite database.
How to handle it?

Comment: What is the actual problem? That the data is still visible in the listview? Or that the data is not deleted in your DB? Because looking at the code pasted here, we only see you deleting the db data. Hence the listview will still show the data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set or bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` and remove the item from this one, e.g.:

```
private ObservableCollecton<DBName> _source;
private void ReadTryoutList_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReadAllDBName dbName = new ReadAllDBName();
    DB_TryoutList = dbName.GetAllDBName();
    _source = new ObservableCollecton<DBName>(DB_TryoutList.OrderByDescending(i => i.ID).ToList());
    ListTryout.ItemsSource = _source;
    if (DB_TryoutList.Count == 0)
    {
        statuskosongStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ListTryout.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        statuskosongStack.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ListTryout.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}

private void deleteItemBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as AppBarButton;
    var item = btn.DataContext as DBName;
    if (item != null)
    {
        _source.Remove(item);
        Db_Helper.DeleteQuiz(currentquiz.ID);
    }
}
```

I assume that `GetAllDBName()` are returning an `IEnumerable<DBName>` and that you are displaying `DBNames` in the `ListView`.

Comment: I've tried the code above, but the data on the sqlite database was not successfully deleted. While on listview erased. So if I exit the page and enter the page again, the data is still displayed on the listview because the data on the sqlite database is not successfully deleted. How to handle it?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not overwriting the database on each build? It's the database in the output directory that gets written to. Not the one in your project directory.

Comment: I've managed to delete the data in listview and sqlite database. I forgot to add a function. Thanks